# Solutions of linear system over subfield

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, extension-field

Let $L/K$ be a field extension. Consider two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ over a field K. Suppose that there exist nonzero vectors in $L^n$ such that:
$$Ax=0, By=0, x^T\cdot y =0,$$

Surely matrix equations has solutions in $K$.

Is it possible to find such vector $x',y'\in K^n$ that will also have zero product?

Comment: If $\vec{x}_i, i=1, \ldots, m$  is basis of $\ker A$ over $K$ and $\vec{y}_j, j=1, \ldots, n$ is basis of $\ker B$ over $K.$ Then any solution of $Ax=0$ over any extension $L$ over $K$ is represented uniquely as $\sum_i\alpha_i\vec{x}_i, \alpha_i\in L.$ Similarly, solution $By=0$ is represented as $\sum_j\beta_j\vec{y}_j, \alpha_j\in L.$  Any $x^T\cdot y = \vec{\alpha}^TC\vec{\beta}, x\in \ker A, y\in\ker B$ where $C$ is $m \times n$ matrix, $C_{i,j} = \vec{x}_i^T\cdot \vec{y}_j.$ Hint: use elementary transformations on rows and columns of $C.$

Comment: @dsh Thank you! As far as I understand, since $C$ is a matrix over $K$ then $C \beta$ is $K$-vector for $K$-vector $\beta$. Than surely we can choose any "orthogonal" \alpha\in K^n$? Sorry, but I didn't understand how to use hint here)

Comment: $C$ is over $K,$ yes. When initial matrix $C$ does not contain 0 then using new basis in $\ker A$ (row operations) or $\ker B$ (column operations) one can try to eliminate non-zero elements. The only case left to consider when $\dim\ker A= \dim \ker B = 1.$

Comment: @dsh Could you explain why do we care about non-zero elements of $C$? For the last case our solutions will be proportional to constants $\alpha x$,$\beta y$. Then its product is equal to $\alpha\beta x^Ty=$. Since $\alpha\neq 0, \beta \neq 0$, than product of K-vectors should be zero.

Comment: If there are no non-zero elements then one can try other bases, in which $C$ has some zero elements and no need to refer to solution in $L.$ Information about perpendicular vectors is needed only when kernels are 1-dimensional.

Comment: @dsh Sorry for a lot of questions. But do we want $C$ to have zero elements just for general simplification or there are any other purposes?

Comment: When you get zero element in $C$, it means that you get 2 vectors from kernels over $K$, which are perpendicular.

Comment: @dsh oh, of course! I forgot about that. Did I describe the idea of the solution correctly for $dim( ker A)= dim (ker B)=1$?

Comment: Yes, I think so)